# edgarWebR started giving error related to xml2 package

Tags: r, xml2

This worked in mid-February, but stopped as of yesterday. It looks like there might have been some updates to xml2 subsequently, not sure if this is a factor.

library(edgarWebR)

```
filing_list <- 
  edgarWebR::company_filings(
    as.character("AAPL"), 
    ownership = FALSE, 
    type = "10-K", 
    before = "2020207", 
    count = 40, 
    page = 1)
```

> Error in xml2::url_absolute(res[[ref]], xml2::xml_url(doc)): Base URL must be length 1

Using xml2 1.3.0 and edgarWebR 1.0.1, but also tried previous versions of both.

Raised an issue with edgarWebR, but any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem and your post actually helped me fix it.

1: Go into 'packages' on RStudio and delete all versions of the xml2 package.

2: Restart R

3: Run these lines of code:

require(devtools)

install_version("xml2", version = "1.2.2", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

More info here https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages

Answer (score 0):

Author of edgarWebR here - I did a bit of debugging, here is the issue in xml2 I opened that, once fixed, should allow using a current version - https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues/300